# How can I simply pass arguments to parent constructor in child class?

Tags: python

I want to design some derived classes in Python but don't know how to make it very simple without too much effort and code.

Let me explain, I have the following class:

```
class Page(object):
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
```

I want to derive some children:

```
class PageWithImage(Page):
  def __init__(self, name, image):
    # Need I do this boring code? - how to replace it?
    super(PageWithImage, self).__init__(name = name)
    self.image = image
```

How can I skip rewriting the whole list of variables for the call to the super method like `name = name`? (since there can be a lot of such variables)

How can I make it more readable? (less code is often more readable)

I do not like the code I wrote - since auto-completion doesn't work with this code:

```
class PageWithImage(Page):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwrds):
    # Need I do this boring code? - how to replace it?
    super(PageWithImage, self).__init__(*args, **kwrds)
    self.image = image
```

Comment: you could store the variables in an other object/list. This way you only have to pass one reference.

Comment: Yes I can but it bad practice to hide arguments - leads to complicated code and difficult problems. It moves problem to inheritance of arguments classes. Code will be doubled I think so it is not good solution.

Comment: @Chameleon To resume your problem, you want to simplify the parent constructor call by passing all the arguments or some of the arguments? Because, if you don't use the *args or **krwds you won't be able to pull it I think.

Comment: @Raito I want pass subset of arguments form child to parent - if child adds argument image I want pass "all - (image,)" to parent but not do it in such ways `a1 = a1, a2 = a3, ...` if it possible.

Comment: @chameleon: you where searching for a method that eliminates passing all variables via the super call. So you will hide the arguments anyways, right? It makes perfectly sense to have an other class (or a simple list if you want) that stores your configuration for the Page class.

Comment: @kasperTaeymans I do not want use your approach since it forces more code complexity. I suggest you avoid such patterns since it will fast block further code expansion that is my experience. Passing configuration to configure object require another constructor with same problem.

Comment: @Chameleon did u find a solution?

Answer (score 23):

I think that your code is quite broken or untested (bad indentation, bad syntax), because it won't run currently, maybe you should edit.

But if you want to simplify your "super call" :

```
class PageWithImage(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PageWithImage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

It will takes all arguments and keywords arguments (remove the **kwargs if you don't need keywords arguments).

Yes, less code is often more readable, but it's not always the case, list comprehensions, complicated functions using *args and **kwargs, lambda, etc... can be *obscure* sometimes for a developer *even if they save +20 characters*.

So, if the number of parameters can be easily ~10, you should try to re-design or stuff them into a dictionnary, or a list, depending on the nature of these parameters.

Comment: I just type code in SO for some example - yes it is broken but good remark - I will fix now.

Comment: Want avoid specifing __init__(self, *args, **kwrds) in children. I can try tricks with locals() whatever I think maybe there is better solution. Nothing is always good - words like all, always, nothing, never is god words whatever I am not god and can not know "all" but human only :)

Comment: @Chameleon I understand, but your only last option is tricking with locals(), I think. And that would lead to more complicated code as you should know which arguments you should pass to your parent class. And if you pass all, you may have perf issues (as it is a new function call => new stack). Imo, it's a bad idea. Even you don't like the __init__(self, *args, **keywords). Else, you have the object/list encapsulation technique.

Comment: You have right that performance will suffer when I will use locals() and will pass some of them even it will be `parent_kwrd dict((x, y) for x, y in locals().items() if x not in ['image'])`.

Comment: @Chameleon Furthermore, it will be hard to manage your implementation if you add a new argument to a child, you will need to add it a list of child-arguments. It can be very confusing.

Comment: Indeed it lead to strange code - I will do regex to generate readable code :) Like `([\w_]+)([^,])` than replace $1 = $1 and mapping of argument will be done ... than copy-paste :)

Comment: Complicated solution for simple problem solvable by *args, **kwargs, it's quite un-pythonic but it's your choice !

Comment: Master is not naming all :) Don't get set into one form, adapt it and build your own, and let it grow, be like water. Empty your mind, be formless, shapeless — like water. Now you put water in a cup, it becomes the cup; You put water into a bottle it becomes the bottle; You put it in a teapot it becomes the teapot. Now water can flow or it can crash. Be water, my friend. - Bruce Lee. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=APx2yFA0-B4

Answer (score 12):

There's no way to extend an argument list at the end in a easy way. If you want to do that, you pretty much need to write out all the arguments each time.

You can however extend the arguments at the start:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, base_arg0, base_arg1, base_arg2):
        pass

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self, derived_arg, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
```

You'd call this with something like `Derived(da, ba0, ba1, ba2)` (note that the derived arg comes before the base args).

In Python 3, you can also specify keyword-only arguments, by putting a bare `*` in the argument list:

```
class BaseKW(object):
    def __init__(self, *, base_arg):
        pass

class DerivedKW(BaseKW):
    def __init__(self, *, derived_arg, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

You could call this with either `DerivedKW(derived_arg=da, base_arg=ba)` or `DerivedKW(base_arg=ba, derived_arg=da)` (the order of the keyword arguments in the call does not matter).

Comment: That is some idea to change arguments order I need test this approach it looks promising - we will loose order of arguments but it not matter if keywords will be force by design. I think about locals() - 'new arguments'.

Comment: Best answer! Thank you. Highly effective second part...makes debugging of class hierarchy easy with keyword arguments (when they are missing, the debugger explicitly says which one!).