# Passing down arguments from App to Children Classes

Tags: python, kivy

I've initialized my primary Kivy app class with an argument. Let's call it `x`. I need to pass this `x` value down to other classes in the app. How do I go about doing that?

For example, I have setup another `GridLayout` class to take the value `x` in it's `__init__` too. I tried to call this `GridLayout` in the main `App` but it returns this following error.

`TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'`

I've supplied the value for sure.

Here's the total code.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class MainWidget(GridLayout):
    x= StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self, x, **kwargs):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x= x

class App(App):
    def __init__(self, x) -> None:
        App.__init__(self)
        self.x= x
        self.run()

    def build(self):
        App.title = 'Title'
        return MainWidget(self.x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App(x='Value of X')
```

Not able to figure how to pass down arguments. If this is not feasible, can someone tell me what would be the right way to approach this problem?

Comment: your mainwidget class isnt a child of app. i dont understand what youre trying to do

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28399131/how-can-i-simply-pass-arguments-to-parent-constructor-in-child-class

Comment: This is not a regular Python script. It's a Kivy app. The build function handles all of that. You can just remove the x from the equation and the app will run perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `StringProperty`, then you can just reference that property when you create the instance of your `App` or your `MainWidget`. Kivy will automatically handle arguments like `x='Value of X'` if that class has a property named `x`. Note that every `Widget` already has an `x` property, so that is a bad choice of property name. Here is a modified version of your code that uses the above suggestions:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MainWidget(GridLayout):
    x_val = StringProperty('')  # do not make another x property

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        Clock.schedule_once(self.add_label)

    def add_label(self, dt):
        self.add_widget(Label(text=self.x_val))

class App(App):
    x = StringProperty('')

    def build(self):
        App.title = 'Title'
        return MainWidget(x_val=self.x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App(x='Value of X')
    app.run()
```

Comment: Perfect. This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you so much. And yes, my variables are named differently. I just replaced it with `x` when posting here so I can avoid using those variable names.

Thank you so much again. It works as intended.

Comment: Additional question, is it possible to access the properties of one class in another class without passing them explicitly ? I was wondering if I had two layouts, can I use the properties set for either of those classes in the other class?

Comment: Yes you can, but you must access them through an instance of the containing class. In my example above, you can reference the `x_val` as `instance.x_val` where `instance` is the instance of `MainWidget`. Trying to use `MainWidget.x_val` will not work.

Comment: Thank you., Just to clarify, using instance.<value> will reference it as long as it is being called by the entire app in some way or the other? I'm guessing the value name has to be unique across all classes?

Comment: I don't understand your question, but in my answer you can reference `instance.x_val` from anywhere in your app, as long as `instance` is a reference to the instance of `MainWidget`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried instantiating the main class and passing the value to gridLayout?

```
x = "username:blessedcoder"
myapp = App(x)

widget = MainWidget(myapp.x)
```

Comment: i dont think 2 separate classes will communicate with each other without you doing it for them

Comment: Yes. Same error. As long as the `x` exists on the MainWidget class, it return this error for me.

In Kivy, they all communicate. Basically the `build` command does that. So I am wondering how to pass down arguments.

Comment: ok ill have to put this in a file and see

Comment: I updated the original post with the full code to make the Kivy app run.

Comment: can i ask why you define x at the class level and also do self.x in the same class?

Comment: So I can try and pass the x in the build function of the App class.

Comment: sorry im not good enough with classes yet i just do functional